# С# WPF Console.WriteLine перенаправление

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть приложение WPF, в нем код

```
#if DEBUG
            Console.WriteLine("Debug informathion");
#endif
```

Как перенаправить этот Console.WriteLine в отдельное окно такое же, как и в обычном консольном приложении?

Прим.: по умолчанию выводится в вывод, но там выводится также информация об отладке программы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно еще классом [Debug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.debug.aspx) воспользоваься или в отдельный файл выводить или в [EventLog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx)

[Как добавить консоль в форму](http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread329819.html)

Answer (score 0):

Я как-то создавал приложение Windows Forms, которое собирал с опцией Console Application. В результате получалось приложение с двумя окнами, консольным и основным.

Answer (score 0):

В настройках проекта установить следующие свойства:

```
<PropertyGroup>
     <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
     <DisableWinExeOutputInference>true</DisableWinExeOutputInference>
</PropertyGroup>
```

[См. документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop#disablewinexeoutputinference).